# how does a rails controller render by default the view for that action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a bespoke CRM software in ruby. Im therefore interested in how rails does the view rendering (by default) for each method. For example index method loads index.html.erb? Because I want to replicate this functionality in the controllers I am building in my application (I understand this is somehow inherited from the base controller)

Comment: Its just the Rails magic.By default it always look for a view file which is of the name of method. Eg :- `index` method renders `index.html.erb`.

Comment: Have a read through the Rails Guide on layouts and rendering: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: If you want to build a new view, you will first need to create a new route for it. Then create a contoller action, and a view file. To see the routes and where they point to, run `rake routes` in the terminal

Answer (score 1):

Just to expand on my comment: To create a new view, register a new route. Here is what I did in my app to create a new "print_list" view in my orders controller. In my  routes.rb file I have (for example):

```
 resources :orders do
   collection { get :print_list }
 end
```

And in my orders controller:

```
 def print_list
      if current_user
        @user  = current_user
      else
          redirect_to root_url, notice: "Please login."
      end
  end
```

And create a print_list.html.erb file.

Lots more good info [at the routing guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-multiple-resources-at-the-same-time).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replicate the action you can see the source code as an inspiration in the ActionController::Base - Render action.

> http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/render#

Just look at the end for the code in show code.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking for a bespoke alternative to Rails (assuming you find it too heavyweight, etc), you might consider Padrino / Sinatra.  This framework puts you much closer to the low-level HTTP protocols without forcing you to reinvent everything from scratch.

Padrino may not give you the "ten minute blog" application that Rails does, but that's just the point: so much of Rails is "convention over configuration", unless you know what's "conventional", you'll be mystified.

Here's a link to Padrino:

```
http://www.padrinorb.com/
```